# System.Threading.Task library in .net specifically Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-extensions

I looked at microsoft's tutorial on Tasks on MSDN... It was good for what it showed, but I still have questions  In there example... found at this URL: [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460699.aspx)

They show an example where they show a Parallel.ForEach() static method call.  In that method call they have four parameters... Does the first Parameter have to be an Array of Ints?  Or could it be a collection or object of any kind that all the thread are working on?  Looks like the second parameter is an Action, which is a delegate that doesn't return a value (or a void).  What the heck is that second variable for?  Thread Local initializer?  Why Initialize to 0?  What the hell is being set  here?  The 3rd parameter is just a delegate (or a function point as I like to think of them with)  is the right side of the lambda expression the actual function?  for instance, could I put the name of an actual function on that side without having to write it out right there?  For example...

```
    public int localSum(int n, ParallelLoopState loopState, int localSum) {
        localSum += n;
        Console.WriteLine("Thread={0}, n={1}, localSum={2}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, n, localSum);
        return localSum;
    }

(n, loopState, localSum) => localSum(int n, ParallelLoopState loopState, int localSum),
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `Parallel.ForEach`? It sounds like it would answer all your questions...

Comment: This is parallel aggregation and it's covered extensively here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963547.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486.aspx):

```
public static ParallelLoopResult ForEach<TSource, TLocal>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TLocal> localInit,
    Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
    Action<TLocal> localFinally
)
```

where you have:

```
Parameters

source
    Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>

    An enumerable data source.

localInit
    Type: System.Func<TLocal>

    The function delegate that returns the initial state of the local data for each task.

body
    Type: System.Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal>

    The delegate that is invoked once per iteration.

localFinally
    Type: System.Action<TLocal>

    The delegate that performs a final action on the local state of each task.
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is an `Action<int>` which is like an ordinary `foreach` loop's body. The simplest way to use `Parallel.ForEach` is the two-parameter overload:

```
Parallel.ForEach(myIntegers, i => loopBody(i));

// non-parallel equivalent
foreach(int i in myIntegers)
{
    loopBody(i);
}
```

`myIntegers` can be any `IEnumerable<int>` and must therefore not necessarily be an array.